# You are not authorized to access this API

Tags: rest-api, webservices, oauth2, google-apps, web

> You are not authorized to access this API Error 403  PUT

I am getting this response when i am updating non admin users signature in gmail using email settings api. The following code is working fine with admin User.

***Code is below.....***

```
public class googleauthclass{

public string authtoken{get;set;}
public string refereshtoken{get;set;}
public string bodyprint{get;set;}
public string ress{get;set;}
public string resp {get;set;}


//Settings needed on the google cloud console.One can store this securely in custom settings or an object.

public static final string CLIENT_SECRET='';//Fill as per your registered app settings in google console
public static final string CLIENT_ID='';//Fill as per your registered app settings in google console
public static final string REDIRECT_URL='https://c.cs18.visual.force.com/apex/Oneview_Google_Calender';

public static final string OAUTH_TOKEN_URL='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
public static final string OAUTH_CODE_END_POINT_URL='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';

public static final string GRANT_TYPE='grant_type=authorization_code';

//Scope URL as per oauth 2.0 guide of the google 
public static final string SCOPE='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/';

//Approval Prompt Constant
public static final string APPROVAL_PROMPT='force';

   public pagereference connect(){

     String x=OAUTH_CODE_END_POINT_URL+'?scope='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(SCOPE,'UTF-8')+'&redirect_uri='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(REDIRECT_URL,'UTF-8')+'&response_type=code&client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&approval_prompt='+APPROVAL_PROMPT;

     pagereference p=new pagereference(x);
     return p;

   }

    public pagereference showtoken(){

   string codeparam=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('code');

            // Instantiate a new http object
    Http h = new Http();

    String body='code='+codeparam+'&client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET+'&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URL+'&'+GRANT_TYPE;

// Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(OAUTH_TOKEN_URL);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(body);

// Send the request, and return a response
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

    bodyprint=res.getbody();

    return null;

   }

   public pagereference getevent()
   {
       Http h = new Http();
       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
       String XMLBody= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
                            '<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">'+
                             '<apps:property name="signature" value="hello VT!!! you won." />'+
                             '</atom:entry>';
                             string endpoint='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/{domain here}/{User ID here}/signature';


                 req.setHeader('Content-Length','400');
                 req .setEndpoint(endpoint);
                 req .setBody(xmlbody);
                 req .setHeader('Authorization','Bearer 7ya78DSA&Y8asyd');
                 req .setHeader('Content-Type','application/atom+xml');
                 req .setMethod('PUT');

       HttpResponse ress = new Http().send(req);
       resp = ress .getBody()+req.getmethod();
       return null;
   }


}
```

Comment: I hope you are giving value for CLIENT_SECRET and CLIENT_ID,Right?

Comment: Yes, I am giving right values. This works well for the admin user and updates admin signature. But when I am updating other users signature. then its giving error i.e.( "You are not authorized to access this API Error 403").

Comment: Is the 403 error coming from Salesforce or Google? It seems more likely that Google is rejecting the API call from their end.

Comment: yes it is coming from google.

Comment: Is it specific to System Admin profile or a particular admin user?

Comment: It is for all users in same domain.

Comment: can we send same id(admin user id) every time in signature.

Comment: yuppp...we can send admin user id  every time. while taking the token from google. There is problem when we are using client's  access token which is generated from client's refresh token  to update his signature. it is saying that "you are not authorized to access this API";

Comment: The answer lies within your question. The Email API from google is meant for Admins to modify user settings, not for users to modify user settings. You need to authenticate with the admin credentials and then post with the appropriate google username. Check out the Email API docs: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/